# Spectacle missing features in 23 version

Tags: linux, screenshot

I have Spectacle 23.08.4

In 22 version, i remember that was possible select transparent color and highlight a rectangular region. in 23 i can't find transparent color in filling option..(attached screen) it's OK....I'm doing it wrong?!

thanks in advance
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!!
i've installed Ksnip!
it have old Spectacle features!
thanks
:))